# Rails: user create hitting other validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a regular users model with address columns. But when a person attempts to register with email and password he receives the error: zip address and town cannot be blank. All you should need to register is email and password. How do I fix user creation ?

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :zip, :state, :town, :address, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,

      attr_accessor :password
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_E_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :password, presence: true, format:{  with: VALID_P_REGEX }, if: proc{ password_salt.blank? || password_hash.blank? } 
      validates :zip, format: { with: VALID_ZIP_REGEX }
      validates :address, length: { minimum: 5 }
      validates :town, length: { minimum: 4 }
    end
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end 
end
```

Error:

```
!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Phone number is invalid, Zip is invalid, Address is too short (minimum is 5 characters), Town is too short (minimum is 4 characters)>
```

Comment: You can read more options here : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want the actual behavior to be.

- If you don't want to validate the extra attributes, just remove their validations as Vamsi says.
- If you want to validate the extra attributes, but not on creation of the user object, you can add `on: :update`, like so:

  `validates :zip, format: { with: VALID_ZIP_REGEX }, on: :update`
- If you want want to validate the extra attributes, but only when they've actually been entered, you can add `allow_blank: true` like so (or `allow_nil`, again, depending on what your needs are):

  `validates :zip, format: { with: VALID_ZIP_REGEX }, allow_blank: true`

For more information about validations and their options, check out [the Active Record Validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about making the validation conditional.

```
validates :address, length: { minimum: 5 }, if: :address
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary validates in the model. As simple as that...

If you want to use it only if value exists you can use the allow_nil or allow_blank option of validate. or you can also use the if conditional.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :zip, :state, :town, :address, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,

      attr_accessor :password
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :password, presence: true, format:{  with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, if: proc{ password_salt.blank? || password_hash.blank? }
      validates :zip, format: { with: VALID_ZIP_REGEX }, allow_blank: true
      validates :address, length: { minimum: 5 }, allow_blank: true
      validates :town, length: { minimum: 4 }, allow_blank: true
    end
```

Comment: but wait when i add address information i want it to be validated.

Comment: Yes but there is another page on the app where they may add address info to the user model. I want to make sure those are correct when they come in.

Comment: Then you can go for the condition based validation. `validates :address, length: { minimum: 5 }, if: :address`